# In C#, how can I reference a specific product record based on a button that's clicked in a gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that displays a gridview of products.  Inside this table is a column with a hyperlink called "Details."  I want to make it so that if the user clicks the details cell for that specific product, a new page will open that gives more information on that product.  I'm not sure how I would determine which `Product` record the details link is in and how I would carry that over to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a HyperlinkField which uses the ID of the product in the querystring.

Here's a sample:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewProducts">
  <Columns>
     <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ProductId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetail.aspx?action=edit&id={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductId" DataTextField="ProductId"  />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product Name" DataField="ProductName" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When you bind, the productID automatically goes into the querystring

Answer (score 0):

As far as "linking" your product records, programmers do this using unique identifiers. In most circumstances, you'll use an integer.

Historically, people have used the query string to pass database IDs from one page to another. In ASP.NET, you can do this as well. Alternatively, you could store the product ID in the `Session` and then load that ID from the `Session` in your new page.

Comment: I do not recommend doing this at all. Sending the product id in the querystring is more than sufficient and doesn't consume server resources. Plus, this requires additional work on the developers part to build and maintain.

Comment: Additionally, what if the user wants to have multiple product pages open? Using a session variable limits this potential. Also, the OP says he isn't sure which product was selected so how would he save it to the session?

Comment: @DustinDavis, I mentioned unique identifiers in the first part of my answer. Was that unclear? Secondly, I'm not recommending one approach over the other, and just saying that you **can** do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the productId by index property of the gridview. Using that productId, you can navigate to the details of a particular product.